# parse a string to get needed info

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have a string with different info coming to it, for example

```
string str = "

Description: 
TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT

Note:
TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1

Description: 
TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2

Note:
TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3"
```

and I want to somehow parse it to get this result:

```
resultString1 = "  
Description: 
TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT

Description: 
TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2" 

resultString2 = 
Note:
TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1

Note:
TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3"
```

**Updated**

I am reading this info from a file, so string is filled by a loop, and there is a new line after each Description, and Note,
so probably should be small algorithm that will read until next appearance of Note, and if Note is found will read until next new line.. something like that.

Comment: Can you change the input at all? Are the newlines part of the input?

Comment: Also, does the input text have any format? Will it always be **Description>Note** or you may receive **Description>Description>Note**?

Comment: sounds like you want to read complete lines (`ReadLine`) and then check: if your line contains one of the predefined keys (note, description), then next rows is a value and want to put them together after. You can go with multiple-pass algorithm or with the use of the buffer (storage) to produce result. It is possible to do it straight or by using linq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see that you want ordrer/cut your content.

Here's a possible solution:

```
// string to sort / cut
string str ="
Description: 
TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT

Note:
TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1

Description: 
TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2

Note:
TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3";

//List of string to retrieve tags descriptions
List<String> tagsDescriptions = new List<String>();
//List of string to retrieve tags notes
List<String> tagsNotes = new List<String>();

// Read str and get only the Description content 'sample'
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader( text )) 
            { 
                string line; 
                bool getContent = false;
                while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) 
                { 
                    if(getContent)
                    {
                        tagsDescription.Add(line);
                        getContent = false;
                    }
                    if(line.contain("Description"))
                    {
                        getContent = true;

                    }
                } 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.  I haven't tested this and it isn't very efficient.  Use it as a guide. This assumes you follow the format Description: >> Note:. You would have to do something similar to get the Note variable.  :

```
string input = @"

Description: 
TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT

Note:
TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1

Description: 
TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2

Note:
TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3";

int startPosition = 0;
int descPosition = -1;
string descriptionResults = "";

while (input.IndexOf("Description:", startPosition) > -1)
{
    descPosition = input.IndexOf("Description:", startPosition);
    int notePosition = input.IndexOf("Note:", startPosition);

    descriptionResults += input.SubString(descPosition, notePosition);
    startPosition = descPosition;
}
```

Comment: will try now, and let you know the result... but i am also interesting in example with regex

Answer (score 0):

Using the following regex will work:

```
Description:\s*(.*)
```

Just grab the groups that are created

[Here is a link to the resultant matching](http://rubular.com/r/6YfzuciGkq). I dont know of an online regex tester for .net that can save links

Answer (score -1):

You could use two regex to match the strings you need
For the description something like: `Description:.\r*\n*.*`

And for the note something like: `Note:\r*\n*.*`

```
Regex regex = new Regex("Description:.\r*\n*.*");
        string str1 = @"Description: 
            TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT

            Note:
            TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1

            Description: 
            TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2

            Note:
            TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3";
        string output = string.Empty;
        foreach (var match in regex.Matches(str1))
        {
            output += match;
        }


Regex regex = new Regex("Note:\r*\n*.*");
        string str1 = @"Description: 
            TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT,TEXT

            Note:
            TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1,TEXT1

            Description: 
            TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2,TEXT2

            Note:
            TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3, TEXT3";
        string output = string.Empty;
        foreach (var match in regex.Matches(str1))
        {
            output += match;
        }
```

With a little manipulation you can get your results.

Comment: that's what i am thinking about, just want to see small example

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @AndreCalil Actually, this is an answer....a wrong one as the regex is wrong, but it is an answer

Comment: @JustinPihony He's just giving an idea. "You could use a regex", "you could parse the string", "you could format the input into an XML". This is not an answer, it's just discussion.

Comment: @AndreCalil He phrased it as a could, but this is a solution. If he hadnt proved a regex, then I would be prone to agree

Comment: Now it's an answer. =) Not the correct one, but an answer still